# Prove $b$ union its limit points is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $b$ be a set of real numbers and $L$ the set of its limit points.

Prove, directly from the definition, that $b \cup L$ is closed.

I am having trouble to prove this. Could anyone help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Since you have to work from the definition, and the term can be defined in several (equivalent) ways, what is your definition of *closed set*?

Comment: Hello, and welcome! What have you tried so far? It's much easier to help if we know what you've managed to do, or what ideas you find confusing.

Comment: The set $A$ with its limit points is the adherence of $A$ which is closed

Comment: Of course, this is $\overline{A}$, so it is closed. If you don't want to use that, you can take a point in the complement. That is $x$ not in $A$, and not a limit point of $A$. Can you see why this has a neighborhood which is contained in the complement (just consider the negation of the limit point condition)? If so, you have proved that the complement is open, so your set is closed.

Comment: I really appreciate all your quick responses:)
My understanding of closed set is: a set A p\in E R is closed if it contains its limit points.
And we have sort of learned about closure A but I am still bit confused how to use it to do the proof here.

Comment: No, it's not what you understand, since the problem asks you to give a direct proof from definition, so what you have to do now is to skim the book for the definition of closed sets. As others have pointed out, there are a few equivalent definitions for closed sets. So what is the definition that your book uses?

Answer (score 2):

Your definition is that a subset of $\Bbb R$ is closed if it contains all of its limit points, so in order to show that $A\cup L$ is closed, you must show that if $x$ is a limit point of $A\cup L$, then $x\in A\cup L$.

Suppose that $x$ is a limit point of $A\cup L$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains a point of $A\cup L$ different from $x$. If every one of those open intervals contains a point of $A$ different from $x$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$, so $x\in L\subseteq A\cup L$, and we’re done. Suppose, hoping to get a contradiction, that $x$ is **not** a limit point of $A$. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is either empty or just $\{x\}$. On the other hand, $x$ **is** a limit point of $A\cup L$, so $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains some $y\in A\cup L$ with $y\ne x$. Clearly this means that $y\in L\setminus A$. Now let $\delta=\min\{y-(x-\epsilon),(x+\epsilon)-y\}$.

1. Show that $(y-\delta,y+\delta)\subseteq(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.
2. Explain why $(y-\delta,y+\delta)\cap A\ne\varnothing$.
3. Explain why this is a contradiction.

Comment: I really thx for ur answer however, I am finding it is really hard to proof this by contradiction.
SO I just try to do :
Suppose that x is a limit point of b∪L. Then for each ϵ>0, vϵ intersect b exclude x is not empty so then x is an element of L.
I am not quite sure am I on the right track now but I am having trouble to prove that vϵ intersect b exclude x is not empty and L is closed.
could anyone help me with that plz?